# java heap size is increasing

Tags: java, jboss, heap-memory, jvm-arguments

Mine is typical java healthcare application, it is running on jboss6 server, while in production environment for every 3 to 4 hours java heap size raising to 7GB afetr that application getting slowed, then we will restart the jboss, can any one help me

Comment: Without knowing ur stack how can anyone help ???

Comment: Does this problem occur when you run 3 to 4 hours in your development environment?